# How `transform` in mongoose schema works?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Picture of my user model :[image]
In my user model I have this as second argument to my user model, to delete `__v` and replace `_id` by `id`:

```
  {
    toJSON: {
      transform: function (doc, ret) {
        ret.id = ret._id;
        delete ret._id;
        delete ret.password;
        delete ret.__v;
      },
    },
  }
```

In my signin router I have something like this :

```
const existingUser = await User.findOne({email});
console.log("existingUser*", existingUser)
res.status(200).send(existingUser);
```

I got this from my console.log

```
 {
  _id: 5fe81e29fdd22a00546b05e3,
  email: 'chs@hotmail.fr',
  password: '0636b425ef0add0056ec85a5596eacf9ff0c71f8c2a1d4bad068a8679398e11870df12262722b911502eacb5fca23cef0cdd3b740481102ead50c58756d14a34.3f82d856ad93bc99',
  __v: 0
}
```

But in postman I received this :

```
{
    "email": "chs@hotmail.fr",
    "id": "5fe81e29fdd22a00546b05e3"
}
```

I know that with transform, "if set, mongoose will call this function to allow you to transform the returned object".
But could someone explain to me when the 'transform' occurs to justify the difference between the console.log and the data I received in postman ?
Does this have something to do with asynchronous ?

Comment: i didnt undertand your problem, do you want to replace id with _id and remove __v ?

Comment: Everythink works fine. What I don't understand is why different output between the console.log(existingUser) and  res.status(200).send(existingUser);
Same variable but outputs are different as explained above.

Comment: Are you sure that is happening ? I don't believe that your server would respond differenly for postman and console.log; Most probably your console.log argument and res.send argument would be different

Comment: Also, try using toObject() method with transform property like ```userSchema.options.toObject.transform = function(doc, output, options) {
 delete output.__v;
return output;
}```

That is a very helpful functionality. Read more [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`res.status(200).send(existingUser);` looks like `expressjs` (or look-alike) controller code, so i'll assume it is Express.

`.send(body)` method sends response to the client browser as a string (well, technically). So, before actual transmission, the `body` argument is converted to `string` if it isn't a string already. `existingUser` in your code isn't a string, it's a mongoose object, so `express` casts it to a string, effectively this will be similar to the following code:

```
res.status(200)
  .send(
    existingUser.toString() // .toString() here is the key
  );
```

Under the hood, `mongoose` object's `.toString()` is proxied to `.toJSON()` method, so your code becomes equivalent to following:

```
  ...
  .send(
    existingUser.toJSON() // .toJSON() here
  );
```

...and `.toJSON()` method is what takes into account the `transform(doc, ret)` option, that you specified for the mongoose schema.

`console.log()` on the other hand, does not use underlying `.toString()`/`.toJSON()` methods of the arguments. If you want to print to console the result, that would be received by the end consumer (postman, f.e.), then you should call the transform manually:

```
console.log(existingUser.toJSON()); // like this, transformed, but not stringified
console.log(existingUser.toString()); // or like this, but already stringified
console.log(JSON.stringify(existingUser, null, 3)); // or transform and then stringify with custom formatting (3-space tabulated instead of default single-line formatting)
```

The whole transform chain looks like this:

```
Model
  -> `.toJSON()` 
    -> Mongoose transforms model internally into POJO
      if custom transform is defined
      -> Mongoose passes POJO to user defined `transform(doc, ret)`, 
         where `doc` - original document, `ret` - internally transformed POJO
        -> `ret` is returned
      else
      -> POJO is returned
```

Answer (score 1):

In Mongoose, the transform option in a schema allows you to modify the object that is returned from the database before it gets returned to the application. The transform function takes the raw MongoDB document as an argument and should return the transformed object that will be returned to the application.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const mySchema = new Schema({
   field1: String,
   field2: Number
}, {
   toObject: {
      transform: function (doc, ret) {
         ret.id = ret._id;
         delete ret._id;
         delete ret.__v;
      }
   }
});

const Model = mongoose.model("Model", mySchema);
```

https://www.cltechhome.com/2023/02/how-transform-in-mongoose-schema-works.html